# Paypal SetExpressCheckout returning token, then displaying "This transaction is invalid..." upon redirect

Tags: php, curl, paypal

```
class ExpressCheckout {

static function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    require_once("DataClass.php");
    $API_Data = Data::GetPayPalData();

    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $environment = $API_Data['enviro'];
    $API_UserName = urlencode($API_Data['user']);
    $API_Password = urlencode($API_Data['pass']);
    $API_Signature = urlencode($API_Data['sig']);
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('72.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

static function send() {

require_once("DataClass.php");
$API_Data = Data::GetPayPalData();
// Set request-specific fields.
$paymentAmount = urlencode($API_Data['pay']);
$currencyID = urlencode($API_Data['currency']);         // or other currency code ('USD', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
$paymentType = urlencode($API_Data['type']);            // or 'Sale' or 'Order'

$returnURL = urlencode($API_Data['return']);
$cancelURL = urlencode($API_Data['cancel']);
$bad = urlencode("MESS subscription");

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr = "&CANCELURL=$cancelURL&REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0&NOSHIPPING=1&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=$paymentAmount&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=$paymentAmount&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0&RETURNURL=$returnURL&L_BILLINGTYPE0=RecurringPayments&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=$bad&L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0=$bad&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";

// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = ExpressCheckout::PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    // Redirect to paypal.com.
    $token = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"]);
    $payPalURL = "https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $payPalURL = "https://www.$environment.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
    }
    //header("Location: $payPalURL"); //commented out to view token and parsed response
    return array($token, $httpParsedResponseAr);
} else  {
    return 'SetExpressCheckout failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true);
}
}

}
```

My code above works correctly for retrieving the token (the response is ACK = 'SUCCESS') but when I redirect to paypal with the token i get the following error:

> This transaction is invalid. Please return to the recipient's website
>   to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow.

I have tried several ways of doing this, searched online, still no luck for 3 days now. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance.

oh and this is called with: `var_dump($token = ExpressCheckout::send($_SESSION['email']));`
`var dump()` being used to see the token and response when `header("Location: $payPalURL");` is commented out.

Comment: Have you came up with the solution?.I too stuck in this same problem.Please post your exact answer.It might help me.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to wrap the example code into a class and came up with the exact same issue. It turned out in my case that the token wasn't being written into the redirect.

Try using var_dump to get the token, then manually entering the url and parameters into your browser's address bar.

Another thought: It looks like $environment is initialized in the PPHttpPost() function but not for the send() function. That could be the problem if you are using the sandbox environment.

Comment: example provide this questions